# How to avoid different letters cases (á, é, í, ó, ú) in search mode - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, searchbar

I'm building an app that should replace the default contacts phone book, and I want to add a search bar for search a contact's name.

For now I have all the contacts in my own DB and a TextWatcher for keep tracking any change in the editText - then builds a query with the char sequence that the user entered.
This is works fine, I'm getting all the contacts the user search like all the contacts starts with "a".
Now I want to add a new functionality to ignore special letters like: á, é, í, ó, ú.

I want that the user could type a and still get all the contacts that starts with á 
the same for e and all the other letters.

Is there a way to do this in the query itself or there is something that Java/Android give us that accomplish that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `java.text.Normalizer` to strip accents.

```
String strippedAccent = Normalizer.normalize(someText, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
```

f you want to use it in a query, you should probably add a field into your DB containing the stripped-down version of the searchable text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if sqlite has a build in solution for this, besides adding another field?

Comment: Not that I know of. sqlite has a collate operator but it is very simple. It can only by used to do case insensitive comparison

Answer (score 0):

[This change](http://code.google.com/p/nubdial/source/diff?spec=svn16&r=16&format=side&path=/trunk/src/com/wysie/wydialer/PhoneSpellDialer.java) worked that quite well for nubdial. It's reasonably fast, too.