# SQLlite like statement replace space with special char

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an SQLlite database with a list of cities. 
My autoCompleteTextView is linked to this database but I have one problem.

There are a lot of cities in my database like this:

Sint-Truiden
Sint-Pieters-Rode
Sint-Rijkers etc...

But a lot of users will just type Sint Truiden and receive no result.

This is what I have so far:

```
String sql = "";
sql += "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CITIES;
sql += " WHERE " + KEY_NAME + " LIKE '%" + searchTerm + "%'";
```

How can I adjust my SQL to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to normalize the search term **and** the database content. For example, you could add to the table a column containing the normalized name. Some normalisation examples :

- Replace any kind of separator (dash, point, multiple spaces) with one space
- Convert to lowercase
- [Remove accents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481218/how-to-avoid-different-letters-cases-%C3%A1-%C3%A9-%C3%AD-%C3%B3-%C3%BA-in-search-mode-android/14481409#14481409)